# Where is the chromium installation installed from npm puppeteer package?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I installed the puppeteer  package on ubuntu and before that I did not have any chromium installation.

How can I run them independently so that I can create profiles, add plugins and then use the same version for puppeter

When I type in the terminal

```
whereis chromium
chromium:
```

edit

I want to try the standard browser because I have a problem with brave browser that:

```
    executablePath: "/usr/bin/brave-browser",

args: [
    '--user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Profile 2'
    `--disable-extensions-except=${my-ext}`, 
    `--load-extension=${my-ext}`,
    '--enable-automation'
  ]
```

I managed to connect to brave and connect the profiles but it does not look like i want. puppeteer opens my profile but there are no extensions and no bookmarks etc..It doesn't look like my profile(s). weird.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium is installed into the `node_modules` folder after NodeJS installation:

```sh
$ npm install -D puppeteer
$ find node_modules -type d -name "puppeteer"
```